# RESTful API - Only 10% POST responses good for same API

Tags: python, rest, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I'm running a RESTFUL API to extract json from a POST. The third party API POSTS to our endpoint which runs in a Flask env on a VM behind nginx served by gunicorn. The problem is that only 10% get through and if I used POSTMAN or curl its the same. I've tested with a stripped down api to remove any processing but get the same results. I'd expect every POST, about 1 every 5 minutes, to get through.

I've looked at nginx config, gunicorn config and flask configs and am either missing something or they're not the problem. Our FW is set to let anything through for this VM. The nginx access logs show up the 90% shortfall as does simply hitting psotman posts manually.

Any ideas?

Flask Code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, Response, json 
from functools import wraps

API_SECRET_KEY = "****"

def not_authenticate():
    message = {'message': "Not Authenticated."}
    resp = jsonify(message)
    resp.status_code = 401
    return resp

app = Flask(__name__)

# assigns route for POSTING JSON requests
@app.route('/api/v1.0/my-api1', methods=['POST'])
def m_api1():
    # AUTHENTICATION
    api_key = None
    if request.headers.get('Authorization'):
        api_key = request.headers['Authorization']
    elif request.args.get('Authorization'):
        api_key = request.args['Authorization']
    if api_key == API_SECRET_KEY:
        if request.method == 'POST':
           return "Authenticated" 
    return not_authenticate()

# assigns route for the default GET request
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return 'test on the index'  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

nginx .conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile off;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";


    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Also here is an example of the nginx access log file showing intermittent sucesses (200's) among the more frequent 404's... Note the ip addresses do change from the 3rdparty api but we can obviously capture it all.

```
*xx.xx.xx.221 - - [08/Jun/2017:07:39:45 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 200 79 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.166 - - [08/Jun/2017:07:39:46 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.139 - - [08/Jun/2017:07:44:46 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.71 - - [08/Jun/2017:07:44:46 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.81 - - [08/Jun/2017:07:49:47 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.62 - - [08/Jun/2017:07:49:47 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.88 - - [08/Jun/2017:07:54:48 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.254 - - [08/Jun/2017:07:54:48 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.68 - - [08/Jun/2017:07:59:47 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 200 79 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.81 - - [08/Jun/2017:07:59:49 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.169 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:04:47 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.62 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:04:48 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 200 79 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.69 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:09:47 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.81 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:09:48 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.31 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:14:48 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.108 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:14:48 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 200 79 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.62 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:19:47 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 200 79 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.43 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:19:49 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.166 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:24:50 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.139 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:24:50 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.33 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:29:49 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 200 79 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.40 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:29:50 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.224 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:34:50 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.166 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:34:50 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.68 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:39:49 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.37 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:39:49 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.88 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:44:49 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.97 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:44:51 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.37 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:49:51 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.221 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:50:06 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.37 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:54:52 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.221 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:54:53 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.40 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:59:54 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.106 - - [08/Jun/2017:08:59:54 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.224 - - [08/Jun/2017:09:04:54 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"
xx.xx.xx.31 - - [08/Jun/2017:09:04:55 +0100] "POST /api/v1.0/my-api1 HTTP/1.1" 404 209 "-" "3rdparty-api-webhooks/0.1"*
```

Comment: If you can share code and more explanation, it would be helpful for the community to answer.

Comment: Strange indeed...but you should look deeper into some logs. It is difficult to say...if it is a timing issue, then you can quickly adapt in order to wait among REST messages...I was for instance using wrong cookie(for authentications) and so on!

Comment: added code to the original post

Comment: Is this a typo: `def my-api1():`?

Comment: no i took out the real api name as it refs the 3rd party I use. the code DOES work as demo'd by the output etc